# AWS Route53 Record Set Deleted, But URL still pointing to Load Balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, amazon-elb

I had a wildcard Record Set (*.my-domain.com) on AWS Route53 which was pointing to my Load Balancer.
So if anyone accessed my domain by adding any subdomain(i.e any-sub-domain.my-domain.com), they would be redirected to my Load Balancer.

Now I have deleted that record set and I forgot to see its TTL, but subdomains are still pointing to my Load Balancer.

Any idea on how I can completely remove or change settings so that it does not point to my Load Balancer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out, I just had to wait a few hours before the deletion of that Record Set took effect.
After some ours, It stopped pointing to my Load Balancer.
But I still couldn't figure out the exact time when it took effect.

Comment: Its because DNS TTL => https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_to_live

Comment: Thanks. I mentioned that I forgot to see its TTL when deleting the record set. That is why I couldn't figure out the exact time.